# Как расположить изображения сеткой?

Tags: php, html, css, framework

Здравствуйте. Есть код который выводит изображения из директории на страницу. Изображения идут друг за другом. Мне нужно расположить изображения сеткой. В данный момент использую для гридов фреймворк [Bulma](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/basics/). Возможно при помощи него можно сделать отображение изображений сеткой.
Подскажите, как это реализовать?

```
<?php
$wimage = "";
$fimg = "";
$path = "pics/"; // задаем путь до сканируемой папки с изображениями
$images = scandir($path); // сканируем папку
if ($images !== false) { // если нет ошибок при сканировании
$images = preg_grep("/\.(?:png|gif|jpe?g)$/i", $images); // через регулярку создаем массив только изображений
if (is_array($images)) { // если изображения найдены
foreach($images as $image) { // делаем проход по массиву
$fimg .= "<img src='".$path.htmlspecialchars(urlencode($image))."' alt='".$image."' />";
}
$wimage .= $fimg;
} else { // иначе, если нет изображений
$wimage .= "<div style='text-align:center'>Не обнаружено изображений в директории!</div>\n";
}
} else { // иначе, если директория пуста или произошла ошибка
$wimage .= "<div style='text-align:center'>Директория пуста или произошла ошибка при сканировании.</div>";
}
echo $wimage; // выводим полученный результат
?>
```

Comment: тут не ваша ситуация описана? https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/tiles/ ближе к концу страницы

Comment: Да, но я не понимаю как именно сделать так чтобы каждая картинка была была отдельно. Там просто примеры с блоками, а как мои изображения раскидать по сетке ?